# Browser that has an auto refresh feature built in (or as add-on for Chrome)

Tags: windows, web-browser

I am looking for safe and clean (does not spy on the user) auto refresh add-on for Google Chrome. My research led me to one with a bad reputation, there are many ones in the store, but I can't tell which is safe and which is not. Do you have any suggestions?

Alternatively I can use another browser. Is there any browser other than Chrome that has this feature built in but without an add-on (I guess IE and Opera don't support this naively without an add-on)?

Note: Opera used to support the auto refresh without add-ons but the current version does not (at least I can't find it anymore).

Answer (score 1):

Noone can really tell you if something is ***safe and clean*** unless he's a security researcher that has done a thorough analysis... But I'm using [**Staying Alive for Google Chrome**](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/staying-alive-for-google/lhobbakbeomfcgjallalccfhfcgleinm) which is pretty reputable and works well.

Comment: Thanks for providing accurate and helpful information.

Answer (score 0):

I came across a browser I did not know existed before. Its name is Blisk, it does support the feature of auto refresh naively. Here is the page for it:
I assume it is safe.

[Blisk Browser](https://blisk.io/)

Comment: Are you sure it is the **auto refresh** you are talking about? Here is how they describe it "Blisk refreshes web page automatically **every time you save code changes**. Try to open IDE in one screen, Blisk - in another and focus on web development". Also seems like this is a premium feature which will cost you $10 monthly

Comment: You are correct, it won't work unless you save the file, but then again, unless the browser is built-in the editor, it would never know what version of the file to use. About the $10....I did not know that!